# R gives different answer for log(1e-18) and log(1-0.99999999999999999)

Tags: r, numbers

Could anyone please suggest about why `log(1-0.99999999999999999)` and `log(1e-18)` give different results in R?  Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)